# How to cancel scheduled messages in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have set ActiveMQ Artemis' configuration to redeliver an unsuccessful message after a period of time with a delay, like this

```
attempt no 1. unsuccessful delivery wait for 5 secs 
attempt no 2. unsuccessful delivery wait for 10 secs
...
attempt no nnn. unsuccessful delivery wait for 5 hours
```

The problem is that I don't see messages on the queue that are scheduled and I don't know how to cancel 5 hours waiting period and redeliver the message right now

My questions

1. Why can't I see that message on the queue when I execute `browse()` function on the Artemis GUI Console? I can only see that message when I execute `listScheduledMessages()`. Had I not tried `listScheduledMessages()` I would be wondering why have I lost a message.
2. Is there any way to repeat a message without waiting for the next 5 hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't see scheduled messages when you use the `browse()` management method because technically scheduled messages are not *on* the queue. If they were on the queue they would be delivered to consumers.

There is currently no way to repeat a message without waiting for the scheduled time to arrive. However, you could get the message's ID using `listScheduledMessages()` and then pass that ID to `removeMessage(long)` to delete the message and then resend it with a different (or no) schedule.